# Sending a complex object to a service stack using a GET request

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, web-services, servicestack

For a while all my [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/) services have been using the `POST` verb for incoming requests sent by clients. In this particular scenario though, I want to use the `GET` verb, and I want to be able to pass a fairly complex object (for example, containing arrays.)

This is my ServiceStack code:

```
[Route("Test")]
public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    public Criteria Criteria { get; set; }
}

public class Criteria
{
    public string Msg { get; set; }
    public string[] Keys { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : ServiceInterface.Service, IGet<TestRequest>, IPost<TestRequest>
{
    public object Get(TestRequest request)
    {
        return HandleRequest(request);
    }

    public object Post(TestRequest request)
    {
        return HandleRequest(request);
    }

    private object HandleRequest(TestRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

        if (request.Criteria == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Criteria is null.");

        return new TestResponse
        {
            Text =
                String.Format(
                    "Text: {0}. Keys: {1}",
                    request.Criteria.Msg,
                    String.Join(", ", request.Criteria.Keys ?? new string[0]))
        };
    }
}
```

Which is consumed by an HTML application with the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when($.ajax({
        url: '/Test',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            "criteria": JSON.stringify({
                "msg": "some message",
                "keys": ["key1", "key2"]
            })
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }));
});
```

My Criteria object gets created but the `Msg` and `Keys` properties are null.

With the following `POST` example, the application works as intended:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $.when($.ajax({
            url: '/Test',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "criteria": {
                    "msg": "some message",
                    "keys": ["key1", "key2"]
                }
            })

        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }));
    });
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What's the actual JSON that gets published? e.g. use Fiddler or WireShark to find out.

Comment: The JSON that gets published is:

Request URL:

http://localhost:1770/Test?criteria=%7B%22msg%22%3A%22some+message%22%2C%22keys%22%3A%5B%22key1%22%2C%22key2%22%5D%7D

Resulting in:

criteria:{"msg":"some message","keys":["key1","key2"]}

Answer (score 1):

Note: You can't mix and match JSON strings with a JSON object (that is, typed [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)).

You're trying to send a serialized JSON string which gets escaped in a JSON string, for example:

```
"{\"msg\":..."
```

On the wire into a POCO which is expecting a JSON object, for example:

```
{"msg":...
```

If the criteria was a string, for example:

```
public class TestRequest : IReturn<TestResponse>
{
    public string Criteria { get; set; }
}
```

It should work, otherwise you need to change your JSON request to send a JSON object and not a JSON object serialized + escaped into a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

When you use JSON.stringify with a [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request, the query string is not well-formed...